# Spring Aspect doesn't work if bean is instantiated manually first

Tags: spring, spring-boot, aspectj, spring-aop

I have a simple aspect like below

```
@Aspect
public class PersistentAspect {

    @AfterReturning("@annotation(org.aspect.PersistentOperation)")
    public void log(JoinPoint jp) {
        System.out.println("aspect call");
    }

}
```

and an `AppConfig` like below

```
public class AppConfig {

    private Integer num;
    private String text;

    public Integer getNum() {
        return num;
    }

    @PersistentOperation
    public void setNum(Integer num) {

        this.num = num;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    @PersistentOperation
    public void setText(String text) {

        this.text = text;
    }

}
```

And configuration class like below

```
@EnableWs
@Configuration
public class WsConfig extends WsConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(List<EndpointInterceptor> interceptors) {
        AppConfig config = config();
        interceptors.add(new CustomValidatingInterceptor(schema(), null));
    }

    @Bean
    public AppConfig config() {
        AppConfig config = null;
        config = new AppConfig();
        return config;
    }

    @Bean
    public PersistentAspect persistentAspect() {
        PersistentAspect persistentAspect = new PersistentAspect();
        return persistentAspect;
    }
}
```

If I use below in the `addInterceptors`

```
AppConfig config = config();
```

The `Aspect` will not work. The obvious solution I have is to change the code to

```
AppConfig config = new AppConfig();
```

Now what I want to understand is, is there a config in which `AppConfig config = config();` could still be made working. I assume that when spring initiates the Bean, it can make an AOP proxy of the `AppConfig`, and when I initiate the bean it interferes with that process somehow. What is the spring/spring-boot way of handling this?

Below is the `pom.xml`, so basically latest `Spring 5.0.5`

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

**Edit-1**

Before posting the I had already adding a `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy`, but that had not helped.

The git repo to try the issue is on below

https://github.com/tarunlalwani/spring-aop-so-50084308

Answer (score 0):

Your `AppConfig` bean (which you initialize, correctly, using a method annotated with `@Bean`) needs to be wrapped in a proxy that then executes the aspect logic.

You have to enable this behavior by adding the [`@EnableAspectJAutoProxy`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/EnableAspectJAutoProxy.html) annotation to your `WsConfig` class.

By the way: it is totally correct to use

```
AppConfig config = config();
```

in your `addInterceptors` method. Spring will return the bean that was created by the `config` method.

Comment: I had already tried that actually. But it didn't work. See https://i.stack.imgur.com/DAlOf.png. Let me share the actual code repo with you

Comment: In [your repository](https://github.com/tarunlalwani/spring-aop-so-50084308/blob/c1034ebaedce3a5d0b20dfb1cc550e779338c83b/src/main/java/org/example/WsConfig.java), the `config` method does not have an `@Bean` annotation. Thus, the `AppConfig` instance is not a bean and will not be proxied by Spring.

Comment: It is there, https://i.stack.imgur.com/flPw9.png ? https://github.com/tarunlalwani/spring-aop-so-50084308/blob/c1034ebaedce3a5d0b20dfb1cc550e779338c83b/src/main/java/org/example/WsConfig.java#L67